# How to hide parent menu automatically if all menu items are hidden via DynamicMenuContent

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

I have implemented menu hiding based on user authentication and roles using `DynamicMenuContent`

```
/**
 * Presenter that displays menu item if, and only if the user has the specified role.
 */
public class RoleMenuPresenter
        extends JMenuItem
        implements DynamicMenuContent {
    private static final JComponent[] EMPTY = new JComponent[0];
    private final String roleName;
    private final AuthenticationDelegate delegate = (AuthenticationDelegate) SpringSingleton
            .getBean("authenticationDelegate");
    private final JComponent[] components = {this};
    private final JComponent[] emptyComponents = EMPTY;

    //~ Constructors ===================================================================================================
    /**
     * Constructs this presenter.
     *
     * @param a action to execute
     * @param roleName the rolename
     */
    public RoleMenuPresenter(Action a, String roleName) {
        super(a);
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
    //~ Methods ========================================================================================================

    @Override
    public JComponent[] getMenuPresenters() {

        if (delegate.getStatusBean().hasRole(roleName)) {
            return components;
        }

        return emptyComponents;
    }

    @Override
    public JComponent[] synchMenuPresenters(JComponent[] jComponents) {
        return getMenuPresenters();
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public interface Provider
            extends Presenter.Menu {
        @Override
        RoleMenuPresenter getMenuPresenter();
    }
}
```

Secured `Action` implements `RoleMenuPresenter.Provider`. Menu items are hidden as expected. There is a problem however, if all items of a menu are hidden, the menu still is displayed. Example:

- File

  - Print
  - Exit
- Transaction

  - A
  - B
  - C

If A, B, and C are hidden, Transaction is still visible. My question is how to automatically hide Transaction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work. `MenuFolderUtil` is used to calculate empty folder paths. `ReheatMenus` is used to warm up the menus. `DynamicLayerContent` is file system provider to provide in memory `*_hidden` folders. `MenuVisibilityUtil` is the main entry.

### MenuFolderUtil

```
final class MenuFolderUtil {

    static Set<String> findEmptyFolder() {
        Set<String> folderPaths = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        FileObject file = FileUtil.getConfigFile("Menu");
        Enumeration<? extends FileObject> folderEnumerations = file.getFolders(
                true);
        while (folderEnumerations.hasMoreElements()) {
            FileObject element = folderEnumerations.nextElement();
            folderPaths.add(element.getPath());
        }

        Enumeration<? extends FileObject> childrenEnum = file.getChildren(true);
        while (childrenEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            FileObject element = childrenEnum.nextElement();

            if (element.isFolder()) {
                continue;
            }
            FileObject parent = element.getParent();
            String parentPath = parent.getPath();
            if (!folderPaths.contains(parentPath)) {
                continue;
            }

            Action action = FileUtil.getConfigObject(
                    element.getPath(),
                    Action.class);
            if (action instanceof Presenter.Menu) {
                JMenuItem presenter = ((Presenter.Menu) action).getMenuPresenter();
                if (presenter instanceof DynamicMenuContent) {
                    treatDynamicMenuContent(
                            (DynamicMenuContent) presenter,
                            folderPaths, buildParentPaths(element));
                } else {
                    folderPaths.removeAll(buildParentPaths(element));
                }
            } else if (action instanceof DynamicMenuContent) {
                treatDynamicMenuContent(
                        (DynamicMenuContent) action,
                        folderPaths,
                        buildParentPaths(element));
            } else if (action != null) {
                folderPaths.removeAll(buildParentPaths(element));
            }
        }
        return folderPaths;
    }

    private static void treatDynamicMenuContent(DynamicMenuContent presenter,
            Set<String> folderPaths, Set<String> c) {
        JComponent[] presenters = presenter.getMenuPresenters();
        if (presenters != null && presenters.length > 0) {
            folderPaths.removeAll(c);
        }
    }

    private static Set<String> buildParentPaths(FileObject fo) {
        Set<String> paths = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (FileObject parent = fo.getParent();
                parent != null; parent = parent.getParent()) {
            paths.add(parent.getPath());
        }
        return paths;
    }
}
```

### ReheatMenus

```
/**
 * Adapted from {@code org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.MenuWarmUpTask}.
 */
class ReheatMenus
        implements Runnable {

    static void launch() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new ReheatMenus());
    }

    private ReheatMenus() {}

    private static final RequestProcessor RP = new RequestProcessor(ReheatMenus.class);

    private MenuBar bar;
    private Component[] comps;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
            if (bar == null) {
                Frame main = WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow();
                assert main != null;
                if (main instanceof JFrame) {
                    JMenuBar menuBar = ((JFrame) main).getJMenuBar();
                    if (menuBar instanceof MenuBar) {
                        bar = (MenuBar) menuBar;
                        RP.post(this);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                comps = bar.getComponents();
                RP.post(this);
            }
        } else if (comps != null) {
            walkMenu(comps);
        } else {
            bar.waitFinished();
            EventQueue.invokeLater(this);
        }
    }

    private void walkMenu(Component[] items) {
        for (Component item : items) {
            if (!(item instanceof JMenu)) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                Class<?> cls = item.getClass();
                //noinspection JavaReflectionMemberAccess
                Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod("doInitialize");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(item);
                walkMenu(((JMenu) item).getMenuComponents());
            } catch (Exception x) {
                // most likely a NoSuchMethodException on a dynamic submenu
            }
        }
    }

}
```

### DynamicLayerContent

```
/**
 * File system which add system hidden folders.
 *
 * @author Thomas Edwin Santosa
 */
@ServiceProvider(service = FileSystem.class)
public class DynamicLayerContent
        extends MultiFileSystem {
    private static DynamicLayerContent INSTANCE;

    public DynamicLayerContent() {
        // will be created on startup, exactly once
        INSTANCE = this;
        setPropagateMasks(true); // permit *_hidden masks to be used
    }

    static void clear() {
        INSTANCE.setDelegates();
    }

    static void setHidden(Set<String> paths)
            throws IOException {
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileUtil.createMemoryFileSystem();
        for (String path : paths) {
            String pathHidden = path + "_hidden";
            String[] pathSplits = pathHidden.split("/");
            FileObject fo = fileSystem.getRoot();
            for (String folder : pathSplits) {
                fo = FileUtil.createFolder(fo, folder);
            }
        }
        INSTANCE.setDelegates(fileSystem);
    }
}
```

### MenuVisibilityUtil

```
/**
 * Utility for menu security.
 *
 * @author Thomas Edwin Santosa
 */
final class MenuVisibilityUtil {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MenuVisibilityUtil.class);

    private MenuVisibilityUtil() {
    }

    static void refresh() {
        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Set<String> hiddenPaths = new HashSet<>();
                Frame main = WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow();
                assert main != null;
                if (main instanceof JFrame) {
                    JFrame frame = (JFrame) main;
                    JMenuBar menuBar = frame.getJMenuBar();
                    frame.setJMenuBar(null);
                    DynamicLayerContent.clear();
                    try {
                        DynamicLayerContent.setHidden(MenuFolderUtil.findEmptyFolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error("cannot delete menu {}", hiddenPaths, e);
                    }
                    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                    ReheatMenus.launch();
                }

            }
        };
        if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
            run.run();
        } else {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(run);
        }
    }

}
```

To use this, create an Installer in your plugin and call `MenuVisibilityUtil.refresh();`
You may want to call `MenuVisibilityUtil.refresh()` again if there is any user switch.